# how to increase column size in Stimulsoft report viewer automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, stimulsoft

i have a stimulsoft report that shows in bellow.
when my text become too long, second column will increase but other column don't.
how it possible to increase all column in row 2 ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the Grow To Height property of the text components to True.